# Can I make font-weight:bold if user has a special font?

Tags: css, fonts

I have a text with `font-family: "Lucida Grande", tahoma, arial, sans-serif;`

Lucida Grande looks good with font-weight: bold, but tahoma isn't and vice versa: tahoma looks good with normal font-weight, but Lucida Grande isn't.

Comment: And how would be correctly "make"? :) Define? Declare?

Comment: Do you mean you want to specify that Lucida Grande be always bold, but if Tahoma is used instead, it's not bold?

Comment: Can do whatever you like if you provide the font files: http://reisio.com/examples/webfonts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to make font weight depend on font family.

Normally, the value of the `font-family` property should be a list of *similar* fonts so that any of them matches the overall design. Lucida Grande is rather different from Tahoma and Arial, which are rather different from each other. Better alternatives to it are Lucida Sans and Lucida Sans Unicode. Don’t forget to test the appearance using each of the fonts you list down, instead of just copying font family lists from somewhere.

This may remove the need for alternating between normal and bold—any such need is probably a consequence of incompatible font choices.

Comment: Of course I've checked it. 1. Thanksgiving to @reisio (I have added font-face, in modern browsers it's perfect). 2. I changed font-size, now it looks OK (for tahoma & arial).

Answer (score 0):

[RemySharp's font.js](http://remysharp.com/2008/07/08/how-to-detect-if-a-font-is-installed-only-using-javascript/) could be useful. :)

Using jQuery, basically it checks whether the mentioned font exists or not. In your case then, if Lucida Grande exists, you could bold it with `$('.yourelement').css('font-weight, bold');`